# Spark Scala update dataframe

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark

I have problem like this:

```
val data = Seq(("TIM", "FIRST", "A", 1),
                   ("BIM", "SECOND", "A", 2),
                   ("JIM", "THIRD", "B", 1)).toDF("NAME", "POSITION", "GROUP", "INDEX")

    data.show()
    data.printSchema()

    val title = Seq(("A", "MASTER"), ("B", "TEACHER"),
                    ("C", "STUDENT")).toDF("LETTER", "DEGREE")

    title.show()
    title.printSchema()

+----+--------+-----+-----+
|NAME|POSITION|GROUP|INDEX|
+----+--------+-----+-----+
| TIM|   FIRST|    A|    1|
| BIM|  SECOND|    A|    2|
| JIM|   THIRD|    B|    1|
+----+--------+-----+-----+

root
 |-- NAME: string (nullable = true)
 |-- POSITION: string (nullable = true)
 |-- GROUP: string (nullable = true)
 |-- INDEX: integer (nullable = false)

+------+-------+
|LETTER| DEGREE|
+------+-------+
|     A| MASTER|
|     B|TEACHER|
|     C|STUDENT|
+------+-------+

root
 |-- LETTER: string (nullable = true)
 |-- DEGREE: string (nullable = true)

//Final result
+----+--------+-------+--'--+
|NAME|POSITION|  GROUP|INDEX|
+----+--------+-------+-----+
| TIM|   FIRST| MASTER|   1 |
| BIM|  SECOND|      A|   2 |
| JIM|   THIRD|TEACHER|   1 |
+----+--------+-------+-----+
```

I tried several things:

```
val result = data.withColumn("GROUP", when('INDEX === 1, ???????????))
```

Where are question marks are I tried calling UDF but I cannot get current row value from GROUP to pass as parameter to UDF.
Also tried putting there select to TITLE and GROUP = LETTER and nothing worked.

First dataframe is huge, and other is very small in production.

Are some elegant way without joinig them first and then withColumn on join?

Thank you

Comment: if the other dataframe is small, why aren't you making a broadcast join with it?

Comment: Never came across with broadcast joins and don’t know about performance, will try it if will solve my problem. I was trying to avoid joins. Thank you

Comment: well, yeah you can read about it in the docs, the is some threshold in terms of bytes for which Spark can automatically decide on using this type of join, but if you know in advance it's small enough to fit into memory, a hint on the join type is always the better way. good luck!

Comment: Guess you were right. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a broadcast join :

```
data
  .join(broadcast(title),$"GROUP"===$"LETTER")
  .withColumn("GROUP",when($"INDEX"=== 1,$"DEGREE").otherwise($"GROUP"))
  .drop("LETTER","DEGREE")
  .show()

+----+--------+-------+-----+
|NAME|POSITION|  GROUP|INDEX|
+----+--------+-------+-----+
| TIM|   FIRST| MASTER|    1|
| BIM|  SECOND|      A|    2|
| JIM|   THIRD|TEACHER|    1|
+----+--------+-------+-----+
```

You could also collect `title` to a lookup-map, broadcast this map and use UDF, but there is really no advantage over broadcast join